# Example of non splitting finite extension of characteristic $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

> Find example of non splitting finite extension field of characteristic $p$. (prime number)

---

I know that if characteristic is zero,$\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{3}})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is a correct example.

does this situation arise in characteristic $p$ field?

Comment: $\Bbb{F}_2(t^{1/3})$ is such an extension of $\Bbb{F}_2(t)$. To get a splitting field (=a normal extension) you would also need to adjoin a third primitive root of unity, just like in your characteristic zero example. This does not work for finite fields though, for any extension of finite fields is always Galois and hence also normal.

Comment: You mean an example of non-normal finite extension (= not the splitting field of a polynomial of the base field) an example is $\Bbb{F}_p(t)/\Bbb{F}_p(t^{p+1})$ whose normal closure is $\Bbb{F}_p(t),\zeta_{p+1})=\Bbb{F}_{p^2}(t)$ the splitting field of $x^{p+1}-t^{p+1}$

Comment: @Jyrki , reuns , Thank you !!